# how to spar data from SQL database in Elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I decided to get acquainted with elasticsearch.

How to index a sql database? Is it possible to do this? If so, how?
Using plugins, or write scripts, or what tools do you have?

Comment: Have a look at Logstash, and its JDBC input plugin : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html